# jsPdf using html2canvas.js for export pdf from html is not working for large data

Tags: javascript, html, css, html2canvas, jspdf

Hi I am using jsPdf for making pdf of html content, it is going fine for short content and creating  pdf , but when I am trying to use it on large content with html2canvas.js (for rendering  css), it is not creating pdf.
Any suggestions or sample code for this would be helpful.Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to create pdf for large files. There are primarily two ways to do this :

**1. html -> canvas -> image -> pdf** (I assume you are trying this approach)

**2. html -> pdf** (does not work if html contains svg)

I would suggest you to go for **(2)** unless you have a good reason to go for **(1)** (like if you are have svg content)-- it is quite expensive operation for the browser and there is possibility of the browser crashing too.

**1. html -> canvas -> image -> pdf**

This is very neatly described here - https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/339#issuecomment-53327389

My experience when using this method - crashes when the pdf generated contains more than 2-3 pages. (tested on latest chrome and firefox)

**2. html -> pdf**

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', 'a4');
 var options = {
    pagesplit: true
};

pdf.addHTML($('body'), 0, 0, options, function(){
    pdf.save("test.pdf");
});
```

This is way faster compared to above approach. Generates pdf containing 5-6 pages in 1-2 seconds!

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works like a charm. My only question would be, is there a way to target a specific div inside the body, instead of the hole body?

Comment: yes, use the second approach from the answer and replace $('body') with an appropriate jquery selector of your div. eg. $('#id_of_your_div')

Comment: greetings! can you help me getting all the content from the div and not only what is visible on the viewport.

Comment: How about a 53 page pdf?

Answer (score 1):

[PDFPY](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfpy)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfpy

```
var data = {
    //the key as to be same as below
    input: "./test.html",
    output: "./output.pdf"
}

pdfpy.file(data, function(err, res) {
    if(err) throw err

    if(res) console.log("success")
});
```