# How to convert webpage div using js

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf, html2canvas

I am trying to convert a `<div>` to pdf onlick of a button.

I tried **jspdf**, **pdfmake**,**html2canvas** but i am not able to get a pdf which should

1) Text searchable

2) Size should be less than 3 MB

I tried all, like using **jspdf** and **html2canvas** , i am getting a image which is shown in pdf and pdf goes to 70 MB.

I tried :

[how to use html2canvas and jspdf to export to pdf in a proper and simple way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26481645/how-to-use-html2canvas-and-jspdf-to-export-to-pdf-in-a-proper-and-simple-way)

[jsPdf using html2canvas.js for export pdf from html is not working for large data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250810/jspdf-using-html2canvas-js-for-export-pdf-from-html-is-not-working-for-large-dat)

Please help!!

Comment: Could you please show us your code of what you have tried ?

Comment: Haven't you saw the links which i have provided.. that's what i tried so far